# how to individually call search scopes in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I can't seem to get the scoping examples in spree to work.
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/89cb914efb16eabc4f790c018c0a747a61d55aee/core/app/models/spree/product/scopes.rb

```
1.9.3p429 :021 >  Spree::Product.taxons_id_eq(1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `taxons_id_eq' for #<Class:0x007fb583e8d5d8>
```

Also when are the searches being called?

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/89cb914efb16eabc4f790c018c0a747a61d55aee/core/lib/spree/core/search/base.rb#L44

I tried putting a debugger breakpoint at line 44 of spree::core::base::search but I couldn't retrieve the class of the search variable.

**Update:** It appears that all the other search scopes worked, but just that the method is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want. Take a look at the method add_search_scope. This method is defined in the file below

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product/scopes.rb

This allows you to create the scope and register it as a search_scope (which is causing you problems)